# bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: pipeline, amazon-sagemaker

My Sagemaker pipeline failed when reached Transform step, and the error message returned by the log is:

```
1668824693631 | [ 2022-11-19T02:24:53.631Z ] /usr/local/bin/start_with_right_hostname.sh: line 10: serve: command not found
1668824693631 | [ 2022-11-19T02:24:53.631Z ] bash: no job control in this shell
1668824693631 | [ 2022-11-19T02:24:53.631Z ] bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

All previous steps, including create model step, are working just fine. The log did not help much in debugging. Could someone tell me what's wrong here? Thank you in advance.

I followed the instruction here to create the pipeline
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/define-pipeline.html

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution for this?